# Jena fuseki owl ontology

Tags: semantic-web, owl, fuseki

I installed Jena Fuseki and want to be able to get classes from my own OWL file.
The following query returns the classes from **owl** and **rdfs** but not from **ont**.  How can I retrieve them?  I eventually want to add data to TDB using parts from my own OWL ontology when querying with Fuseki.  I'm using Fuseki version: 2.3.1.

```sql
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix ont: <http://wad.nistorandrei.com/ontology.owl#>

SELECT ?class ?label ?description
WHERE {
  ?class a owl:Class.
  OPTIONAL { ?class rdfs:label ?label}
  OPTIONAL { ?class rdfs:comment ?description}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "the classes from owl and rdfs but not from ont"?  If you've declared owl:Classes or rdfs:Classes in your ontology, this query will retrieve them.  Without seeing your data, we can't help.  What's the content of your ontology?

Comment: When I execute the command above I can get "owl:Thing", "owl:Nothing" ( and others ) as the class, but I don't get ont:Place or ont:Church. You can see the ontology at http://wad.nistorandrei.com/ontology.owl# . Do I need data in table in order to get my ontology displayed ?

Comment: You at least need to *load* your ontology.  As I said in response to [your previous question](http://goo.gl/KbLy2G), just declaring a prefix in a SPARQL query doesn't do anything except defining a shorthand for IRIs.  E.g., I can write a query like `prefix snowy: <http://example.org/snowy.owl#> select ...`;  the query engine doesn't try to load `http://example.org/snowy.owl` or anything like that.  It just means that if `snowy:x` appears in the query, it's the same as `<http://example.org/snowy.owl#x>`.  That's **all**.  You still have to *load* whatever data you want into the datastore.

Comment: The question you're asking is kind of like "I worked with a database machine X yesterday and stored some data.  Today I installed MySQL on machine Y, but my queries don't return anything. Why not?" Just because you defined some data in *one* place doesn't mean you can use it somewhere else without loading it.

Answer (score 3):

The description of your issue makes me suspect that you did not load your ontology in Fuseki.
Declaring prefix ont: http://wad.nistorandrei.com/ontology.owl# will not allow you to query the distant ontology.owl file.

You have to create a dataset (in manage datasets -> create dataset)
and add data to it (existing dataset -> upload data or with a SPARQL UPDATE query)

Then only you can query your data.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added data and it worked.